# How to correctly use threads if the number of cities is very large?

Tags: json, ruby, parsing

How to fix the problem

```
warning: conflicting chdir during another chdir block
```

I get all the places in the city and create a folder with an attached file
how to properly optimize the code and implement the correct work?
How to check if the folder with the file exists then add new text to the existing file?

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'JSON'
require 'thread'

def scrape_instagram_city_page(page)
    cityArray = []
    id = 0
    begin
        instagram_source = open(page).read
        content = JSON.parse(instagram_source.split("window._sharedData = ")[1].split(";</script>")[0])
        locationName = content['entry_data']['LocationsDirectoryPage'][0]['city_info']['name']
        nextpage = content['entry_data']['LocationsDirectoryPage'][0]['next_page'] 
        Dir.mkdir("#{locationName}")
        loop do
            id +=1
            instagram_source = open(page+"?page=#{id}").read
            content = JSON.parse(instagram_source.split("window._sharedData = ")[1].split(";</script>")[0])
            locationsList = content['entry_data']['LocationsDirectoryPage'][0]['location_list']
            locationsList.each do |hash|
                cityArray.push(hash['id'].to_i)
            end
            if nextpage == "null"
                break
            end
        Dir.chdir("#{locationName}") do
            fileName = "#{locationName}.txt"
            File.open(fileName, 'w') do |file|
                cityArray.each do |item|
                    file << "https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/#{item}/\n"
                end
            end
        end
        end
    rescue Exception => e
        return nil
    end
end

threads = []
city = ["https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/c2269433/dhewng-thailand/","https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/c2260532/ban-poek-thailand/","https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/c2267999/ban-wang-takrai-thailand/","https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/c2255595/ban-nong-kho-thailand/","https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/c2252832/ban-na-khum-thailand/","https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/c2267577/ban-wang-khaen-thailand/","https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/c2248064/ban-khung-mae-luk-on-thailand/","https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/c2243370/ban-hua-dong-kheng-thailand/","https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/c2269271/chieng-sean-thailand/","https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/c2256442/ban-nong-phiman-thailand/","https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/c2246490/ban-khlong-khwang-thai-thailand/"]
city.each do |page|
    threads << Thread.new do
        scrape_instagram_city_page "#{page}"
    end
end

threads.each(&:join)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before answering the question, I would note that scraping a site is often against that site's terms of service. You should check into this and make sure you are not doing something illegal.

The "current directory" as changed by `chdir` is a process-wide setting shared by all threads. This is why you're getting an exception when two threads try to change it at the same time. It has nothing to do with how many threads you're creating.

To avoid this problem, don't change the current directory. Just include the directory in the path:

```
def scrape_instagram_city_page(page)
    cityArray = []
    id = 0
    begin
        instagram_source = open(page).read
        content = JSON.parse(instagram_source.split("window._sharedData = ")[1].split(";</script>")[0])
        locationName = content['entry_data']['LocationsDirectoryPage'][0]['city_info']['name']
        nextpage = content['entry_data']['LocationsDirectoryPage'][0]['next_page'] 
        Dir.mkdir("#{locationName}")
        loop do
            id +=1
            instagram_source = open(page+"?page=#{id}").read
            content = JSON.parse(instagram_source.split("window._sharedData = ")[1].split(";</script>")[0])
            locationsList = content['entry_data']['LocationsDirectoryPage'][0]['location_list']
            locationsList.each do |hash|
                cityArray.push(hash['id'].to_i)
            end
            if nextpage == "null"
                break
            end
            fileName = "#{locationName}/#{locationName}.txt"
            File.open(fileName, 'w') do |file|
                cityArray.each do |item|
                    file << "https://www.instagram.com/explore/locations/#{item}/\n"
                end
            end
        end
    rescue Exception => e
        return nil
    end
end
```

Comment: How to increase the speed of information processing?How to effectively use threads?

Comment: That is very subjective and broad and cannot easily be answered here. For example, it is quite likely your major performance bottleneck is either your Internet connection or the site to which you are connecting.

Comment: What is the maximum or effective number of threads that can be used in this case?

Comment: Since it is I/O-bound, not CPU-bound, that cannot be determined. Some might recommend, for example, switching to asynchronous I/O and using just one thread. If you continue to use synchronous I/O, that depends on how long it takes the server to answer.

Comment: How  to switch to asynchronous I/O and how it works?